Custom two-way-data-binding with init values and observables - AngularJs
I have this input angular custom component:
<!--HTML -->
<mat-form-field
    appearance="outline"
    color="accent"
    role="group">
    <mat-label>
        {{label}}
    </mat-label>
    <input
        [formControl]="control"
        [required]="required"
        matInput
        type="text"
        (input)="_onInput()">
    <!--...........--------->
</mat-form-field>

export class InputCustomComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {

  // ...

  @Input() get disabled(): boolean {
    return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(value: boolean) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  }
  private _disabled = false;

  control!: FormControl;
  
  // ...

  @Input() get value(): boolean | string | object | null {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(value: boolean | string | object | null) {
   this._value = value;
  }
  private _value: boolean | string | object | null = null;

  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string | null>();

  constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setFormControl();
    this.required = this.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required) || this.required;
  }

  setFormControl() {
    try {
      const formControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);

      // ...
    } catch (error) {
      // when no exists forms
      this.control = new FormControl({ value: this.value, disabled: this.disabled });
    }
  }

  // ...
}

When I use this component (I just show the usage path without form) with observables.
If first I initialize resource in constructor, the input no take value correctly:
<div class="detail">
      <custom-input-text
        [(value)]="resource.id"
        [label]="t('zip')"
      >
      </custom-input-text>
</div>
...........
resource!: Catalogo;

constructor(
    private service: ExampleService,
  ) {
    this.resource = new Catalogo();
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service
      .getResource("1234")
      .subscribe((resource) => (this.resource = resource));
}

But If I dont initialize (and check in .html) the input take value correctly:
<div class="detail" *ngIf="resource">
      <custom-input-text
        [(value)]="resource.id"
        [label]="t('zip')"
      >
      </custom-input-text>
</div>
...........
resource!: Catalogo;

constructor(
    private service: ExampleService,
  ) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service
      .getResource("1234")
      .subscribe((resource) => (this.resource = resource));
}

The question is: How does this component work? Is it normal in angularJS? Or Do I have any problem?
(Within forms the component is perfect)
